# Solve the differential equation using power series.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

$\displaystyle y^{'} = {\frac{y}{x}} + 1$
cannot be solved for $y$ as a power series $x$. Solve this equation for $y$ as a power series in powers for $ x-1 $.: Introduce $t=x-1$ as a new independent variable and solve the resulting equation for y as a power series in $t$.)

So far I have proved that it cannot be solved for y as power series in terms of x because you get negative exponents. I did solve for x, which equal t+1.

So, the equation looks like $\displaystyle y^{'} = {\frac{y}{t+1}} + 1$.

Can I multiply both sides by $(t+1)$ so the equation looks like $ \displaystyle (t+1)y^{'} = y + (t+1)$?

My solution so far:

$y^{'} = \displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}{n}{c_n}{(t+1)^{n-1}}$
$y = \displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}{c_n}{(t+1)^{n}}$

$ \displaystyle (t+1)y^{'} = y + (t+1)$

$(t+1)\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}{n}{c_n}{(t+1)^{n-1}} = \displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}{c_n}{(t+1)^{n}} + (t+1)$

$\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}{n}{c_n}{(t+1)^{n}} - \displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}{c_n}{(t+1)^{n}} =(t+1)$

$\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}{n}{c_n}{(t+1)^{n}} - \displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}{c_n}{(t+1)^{n}} =(t+1)$

$\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}[nc_n-c_n]*(t+1)^n = (t+1)$

$\displaystyle nc_n-c_n = (t+1)$

$\displaystyle c_n(n-1) = (t+1)$

$\displaystyle c_n = \frac {(t+1)}{n-1} $

Substituing x back in we get:

$\displaystyle c_n = \frac {(x)}{n-1} $

Did I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

> $\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}[nc_n-c_n]*(t+1)^n = (t+1)$
>
> $\displaystyle nc_n-c_n = (t+1)$
>
> $\displaystyle c_n(n-1) = (t+1)$
>
> $\displaystyle c_n = \frac {(t+1)}{n-1} $
>
> Substituing x back in we get:
>
> $\displaystyle c_n = \frac {(x)}{n-1} $
>
> Did I do this correctly?

From this line is is not.

$$
 \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}[nc_n-c_n]*(t+1)^n = (t+1)
\implies \forall n\neq 1\ \ \ nc_n-c_n = 0
$$

At the end, $c_n$ should not depend on $x$!

Note that you can solve the equation directly with the substitution
$$
y(x) = r(x)x
$$